# Ember not showing foreign key field data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have four models

```
//models/exam.js

name: attr('string'),
owner: belongsTo('user'),


//models/question.js

content: attr('string'),
exam: belongsTo('exam')


//models/answer.js

owner: belongsTo('user'),
question: belongsTo('question'),
answer: attr('string'),
remarks: attr('string'),
exam: belongsTo('exam')


//models/user.js

owner : attr('string'),
email : attr('string'),
password : attr('string'),
```

I load the models into a route. Then, when I run the following template code,

```
{{#each model.answers as |ans|}}
<p>{{ans.question.content}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

//route.js

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { hash } from 'rsvp';

export default Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return hash({
            student: this.store.findRecord('student',params.id),
            answers: this.store.query('answer',{
                owner: params.id
            }),
        });
    }
});
```

it shows the output as follows

```
<frontend@model:question::ember276:5>
<frontend@model:question::ember281:6>
<frontend@model:question::ember286:4>
```

why is it showing such an code, why not showning the original content?

Comment: What does your route look like?

Comment: I will update now

Comment: Is the question-relationship loaded from server?

Comment: yes. The backend is done in Django rest framework, and the foreign key relationship between question and answer models are defined there too

Comment: The interesting thing is the problem arises only in this single case, I when I go for `{{ans.question.exam.owner.name}}` it correctly prints the value.

Comment: or even `{{ans.question.id}}` also works

Comment: @Sreenath I think the problem is that you named your property content. Try to rename it and check if this is the problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you said, could you please make it clear?

Comment: Customize your question-serializer and rename content to questionContent. Maybe it will solve your problem. https://codeshare.io/aVB0Kb

Comment: Thanks Mr @asdf. I didn't get the solution right, But I could able to recognise the reason for the error that `.content` will return an ember object of that particular model field

Comment: Really thank you for your help and if you post, then an answer I will verify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you encountered a very special and rare case. The content has a special meaning for ember relationships. That's internal stuff and an end-user should not deal with it. But that's the reason, why you get

```
<frontend@model:question::ember276:5>
```

for

```
{{ans.question.content}} {{!-- .content doesn't return the content attribute --}}
```

I would work around it by changing the attribute's name at server and ember-model. If I server's attribute-name is not mutable, I would customize the ember-serializer. I.e.:

```
//app/serializers/person.js (ember g serializer question)
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    questionContent: 'content' //map server's attribute content to ember-model's questionContent
  }
});
```